# How many two move checkmates exist?

Tags: checkmate, mathematics, fools-mate

I am well aware that Fool's Mate exists. But how many two move checkmates exist in total?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

8 different ways.
2 different ways for f3/f4. 2 different ways for e6/e5. 2 different ways for changing the move order between g4 and f3/f4.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the previously-given answer from Matthew Liu (please give it the checkmark), but I’ll add the standard notation of the solutions since you ask:

1.f3 e5 2.g4 Qh4#

1.f3 e6 2.g4 Qh4#

1.f4 e5 2.g4 Qh4#

1.f4 e6 2.g4 Qh4#

1.g4 e5 2.f3 Qh4#

1.g4 e6 2.f3 Qh4#

1.g4 e5 2.f4 Qh4#

1.g4 e6 2.f4 Qh4#